# Scraping web [VBA] xmlhttprequest

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am stuck with this. I am trying to learn how to use xmlhttprequest with VBA. My intention is to access the following url: "https://micuil.net/".

Once there, I can send values to the following fields, as seen in the image:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXyiF.png)

After pressing the button, the page displays the following information with the data I want to extract:
[image2 (return value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kjMm.png)

I am able to complete what you see in image 1 by code, but I don't know how to get the result (image 2). Any help please?

```
    Function CuitEstimado2(sDni As Variant, sSexo As String) As String
    Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHTTP = New XMLHTTP60
    sSexo = IIf(sSexo = "f", "Mujeres", "Varones")
    sUrl = "https://micuil.net/"
    
    oHTTP.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    oHTTP.send
    sRespuesta = oHTTP.responseText
    oDoc.body.innerHTML = sRespuesta
    
    oDoc.getElementById("dni").Value = sDni
    oDoc.getElementsByName("sexo")(0).setAttribute("checked") = True
    oDoc.getElementById("btn").parentElement.Click
    End Function
```

Comment: It is not possible to interact with xhr. No JS is executed and values that a human enters in input fields must be passed as parameters. For GET queries in the URL, for POST queries as payload in the HTTP header. I haven't looked at how this works for the page. Because when doing a test run with the specified no. and submitting via the submit button, the expected result is displayed, but no network traffic takes place, as far as I could understand. A JS is executed in the browser. Could it be that it is a conversion of the entered number that is taking place locally?

Comment: This page calculate the CUIT from the DNI. I understand that the CUIT is similar to the TIN of other countries (it is a tax identification number, which is obtained from a personal identification number)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea about such numbers. But if there is a conversion rule, then it makes sense to try to figure it out and then write a VBA function that applies it to the known numbers. That would be much faster and all the web scraping would be eliminated.

Comment: Yes! I actually have a function that estimates that number. This is just to try to learn how xmlhttprequest works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Without having done heavy research for the specific website you are using, it may still be possible that the result you are looking for can be found within the response text (assuming I am understanding your dilemma properly).

First, it is recommended to perform a loop through the innerHTML of each element contained in the HTMLDoc. During your loop, use the InStr function to locate the result code as a string.  It is a good idea to store each element that contains that result code into a collection for easy access after the loop.

It does get a bit more complicated from here, because the innerHTML of the corresponding elements may differ when pasting them into Notepad vs. trying to utilize in the VBE. However, if you can identify any unique JS (or other language) characters that will consistently indicate the location of the result code for each request, you may be able to use the Mid function to return the desired result into a string variable.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I see that the result is saved in the following element: id="resultadoCUIL". But after execute the code above, i try odoc.getElementById("resultCUIL").innerText and returns null :(

Comment: @core335 As I wrote above. It is not possible to interact with the response from an xhr query. It is not possible to click a button, it is not possible to execute Java Script and it is certainly not possible to trigger a subsequent query. With xhr only a single file can be loaded from a web server.

Comment: Thank you Zwenn, now it's clear to me

Comment: @zwenn If a loop is performed over all of the HTMLDoc elements for each run of the macro, performance will be rather slow. However, once locating the proper element, if certain identifying characters are consistent within the response text, it still seems possible to manipulate at some level with strings/scripting text files. The result may just be a bit clunky. The difference seems that "getElementById" will not be reliable and a loop must be run for every instance of the macro.

Comment: For the loop, you would be using InStr function to locate the identifying characters that surround the result, rather than the actual result. Then use mid once more on that substring to extract the result.

Comment: @InfrequentCoder Sorry, but the page would have to be called with the correct parameters via xhr so that the number you are looking for is in the responseText. If you can tell what this call should be, that's great. But anything else won't work, because xhr can be used to retrieve exactly one file from a web server that can't be interacted with. Such an access is static. Accessing the right element should be very easy, as long as it is in the document. You almost certainly don't need a loop over all elements or any string magic for that. This is the simple application of DOM methods.

Comment: @zwenn Interesting. It appears according to the earlier comment from core335 that the response text did contain the desired number in element ID "resultadoCUIL". However, when they attempted to call that ID by name afterwards, the return value was null. I don't know too much about other languages, but i know certain doc elements of webpages do not have identifiable properties that remain consistent with every run. This is true for using VBA to parse distance from Google Maps responseText where JS is involved, etc. Not sure if that implies that there is any masking happening with Google

Comment: Core335 has indicated that their code already generates the desired number to the page. In theory, it should only be a matter of trapping that desired number into a substring. Easier said than done